# Crash while re-organizing 1d buffer as 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a 1d buffer which i have to re-organize to be accessed as a 2d array. I have pasted my code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void alloc(int ** buf, int r, int c)
{
    int **temp=buf;
    for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
        buf[i]=(int *)temp+i*c;
}
void main()
{
    int *buffer=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
    int **p = (int**) buffer;
    alloc(p, 4, 4);
//for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    //for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
      //  printf("\n %p",&p[i][j]);


    p[0][3]=10;
    p[2][3]=10;
    p[3][2]=10; //fails here
    printf("\n %d", p[2][3]);
}
```

The code is crashing when i make the assignment.
I have ran the code for different test cases. I have observed that the code crashes when there is an assignment to p[0][x] followed by assignment to p[x][anything] with the code crashing at the second assignment. This crash is seen only when the first index of the first assignment is 0 and for no other indices with the crash happening at the  second assignment having the first index equal to the second index of the first assignment.

For example, in the above code crash happens at p[3][2] after p[0][3] has been executed. If i change the first assignment to p[0][2] then crash would happen at p[2][3]( or p[2][anything] for that matter).

I have checked the memory pointed to by p, by uncommenting the double for loop, and it seems to be fine. I was suspecting writing at illegal memory locations but that has been ruled out by the above observation.

Comment: You can't just cast an `int*` to an `int**`, it's not the same thing. In a 2D array, the first dimension is a 1D array of `int*`.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: The question is more or less "why is this not working", and that's not a good question I agree.

Comment: @Mayerz Yes; Once you reach 3000 rep you will gain the ability to close such questions.

Comment: @this Was this ironic or mean by any way? I wasn't sarcastic or anything.

Comment: @Mayerz I have agreed with you. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/review http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 2):

I think that your fundamental problem is a misconception about 2D arrays in C (Your code is C, not C++).
A 2D array is a consecutive memory space , and the size of the inner array must be known in advance. So you basically cannot convert a 1D array into a 2D array unless the size of the inner array is known at compile time. If it is known, you can do something like

```
int *buffer=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
typedef int FourInts[4];
FourInts *p = (FourInts *)buffer;
```

And you don't need an alloc function, the data is already aligned correctly.
If you don't know the size of the inner array in advance, you can define and allocate an array of arrays, pointing into the 1D buffer. Code for that:

```
int ** alloc(int * buf, int r, int c)
{
   int **array2d = (int **) malloc(r*sizeof(int *));
   for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
       array2d[i] = buf+i*c;   
   return array2d;
}

void _tmain()
{
    int *buffer=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
    int **p = alloc(buffer,4,4);

   p[0][3]=10;
   p[2][3]=10;
   p[3][2]=10; //fails here
   printf("\n %d", p[2][3]);
   free(buffer);
   free(p);
```

}

But it would have been easier to simply build an array of arrays without using the buffer. If you could use C++ instead of C, then everything could be easier.

Comment: Good answer, much less wordy than mine. I think you have your `array2d` malloc a bit big - it only needs to be `r*sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Thanks for the bug correction, I corrected it on the side and forgot to copy here...

Comment: The use of a pointer array referencing the original buffer is a noteworthy approach. This, @Floris, and Dark's answers demonstrate this technique nicely. It is important the OP understand there is no additional allocation of buffer data elements. Only a series of pointers that address various points in the original buffer is required. The original buffer still "owns" the data.

Comment: WhozCraig, you have a good point, this Technic has a combination of benefits that other approaches don't: the memory is consecutive, which can benefit performance, and the use of array dimensions unknown at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your 2D array is actually an array of pointers to arrays. That means you need to have space for the pointers. At the moment you have your pointers in positions 0-3 in the array, but `p[0]` is also pointing to position 0. When you write to 'p[0,3]' you are overwriting `p[3]`.

One (tempting) way to fix it is to allow the pointers room at the start of the array. So you could change your `alloc` method to allow for some space at the front. Something like:

```
buf[i] = (int *)(temp+r) + i*c;
```

Note the `+r` adding to the `temp`. It needs to be added to `temp` before it is cast as you can't assume `int` and `int *` are the same type.

I would not recommend this method as you still have to remember to allocate extra space in your original malloc to account for the array of pointers. It also means you aren't just converting a 1D array to a 2D array.

Another option would be to allocate your array as an array of pointers to individually allocated arrays. This is the normal way to allocate 2D arrays. However this will not result in a contiguous array of data as you have in your 1D array.

Half way between these two options, you could allocate an extra array of pointers to hold the pointers you need, and then point them to the data. Change your alloc to something like:

```
int **alloc(int * buf, int r, int c)
{
    int **temp = (int **)malloc(sizeof (int *)* r);
    for (int i = 0; i<r; i++)
        temp[i] = buf + i*c;
    return temp;
}
```

then you call it like:

```
int **p = alloc(buffer, 4, 4);
```

you also need to free up the extra buffer.

This way your data and the pointers you need to access it are kept separate and you can keep your original 1D data contiguous.

Note that you don't need to cast the result of malloc in c, in fact some say that you shouldn't.

Also note that this method removes all of the requirement for casting pointers, anything that removes the need for a cast is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a 1D block of data, the way to make it accessible as a 2D array is to create an array of pointers - one for each row. You point the first one to the start of the block, the next one is offset by the number of columns, etc.

```
int **b;
b = malloc(numrows*sizeof(int*));
b[0]=temp; // assuming temp is 1D block
for(int ii=1; ii<numrows;ii++)
    b[ii]=b[0]+ii*numcols;
```

Now you can access `b[i][j]` and it will point to your original data. As long as number of rows and columns are known at run time this allows you to pass variable length 2D arrays around. Remember that you have to free the vector of pointers as well as the main data block when you are done or you will get a memory leak.

You will find examples of this if you google `nrutil.c` - this is derived from the trick Numerical Recipes in C uses.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you are absolutely right - writing answers on phones does that to you sometimes... Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This function prototype should be:

```
void alloc(int *buf[][], int r, int c) //buf[][] <=> **buf, but clearer in this case
{
   //*(buf[i]) = 
   ...
}
```

If you want to work on the same array you have to pass a pointer to this 2D array (*[][]).

The way you do it now is just working on a copy, so when you return it's not modified.

You should also initialize your array correctly :

```
p = malloc(sizeof(int *[]) * nb of row);
for each row
  p[row] = malloc(sizeof(int []) * nb of col);
```